# How to Remove 'Home' Link from wp_nav_menu!

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get rid of the 'Home' link from appearing at the top of my links when using `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'news', 'show_home' => false)); ?>`

I tried `'show_home' => false` and `'show_home=0'` but neither worked.

Comment: post the code from wp-head, and allso specify if 'home' is a page added thru wp-admin/pages

Comment: from index.php:   <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="sidebar-menu"> 
 <ul>
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'NewsMenu')); ?>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="content-sub"> 
 <?php query_posts('category_name=news2011'); ?>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <ol class="news">
 <strong><p><?php the_title()?></p></strong>
 <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
 </ol>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div><?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Yes I added it through appearance > menus > and use wp_nav_menu() function to get the menu I've created from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be in your functions.php

```
function page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = FALSE;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'page_menu_args' );
```

EDIT: Dont forget to add this to wherever your menu is supposed to print out:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('echo'=>true));
```

Comment: will it work if i add a page with the tilte 'home' thru wp-admi/pages ? let's wait for some details before we post an answer .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the code abouve.  poelinca I don't know what you mean, in appearances>menus>i don't have home checked, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Oh funk, I don't know if you edited your post or I read it to quickly not see that it says "This should be in your functions.php". What does the echo=>true stand for? By the way it worked, thank you!

Comment: you can pass paramaters to wp_nav_menu through an array like this.  if 'echo'=>false you would need to assign it to a var like this:  $var = wp_nav_menu( array('echo'=>false)); echo $var;

Comment: This is for wp_page_menu, not wp_nav_menu.

Comment: do i add the last line on functions.php file or which file?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
 _nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'topmenu', 'depth' => 0, 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', 'theme_location' => 'topmenu' ) );
```

And I add

```
 function page_menu_args( $args ) {
     $args['show_home'] = FALSE;
     return $args;
 }
 add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'page_menu_args' );
```

In the `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me looking to remove the 'home' link from the **default wordpress menu** (wp_page_menu) and the home is a page (not blogposts), this is one way to solve it:

**in functions.php**:

```
function getPageBySlugname($slugname) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'hierarchical'  => 0,
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );
    $pages = get_pages($args);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page->post_name == $slugname) {
            return $page->ID;
        }
    }       
}
```

**in header.php**

```
wp_page_menu(array(
    'container'         => 'div',
    'show_home'         => false, // Not sure what this is hiding, maybe if you have blogposts as home??
    'echo'              => true,
    'exclude'           => getPageBySlugname('homepage-slugname'), // change this to your slugname
));
```

Answer (score -2):

You're making it way too hard! Instead, use CSS display: none for that particular .home item of a custom menu.    It works like a charm.  Example:

```
menu-blogroll .home {display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score -4):

I used jquery to fix the same.

```
$("div.menu > ul li:first-child").css("display","none");
```

Comment: where did you add this line?