# How to remove HOME link from WP header?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am desperately trying to remove the irritating HOME hyperlink from the header of my WP page. See here, in the upper left corner: http://almagest-centar.hr/?page_id=2 (this is Academica WPZOOM theme).

Is there any way to remove it? I've seen there has been a discussion about this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492495/how-to-remove-home-link-from-wp-nav-menu)), but it doesn't work. My functions.php doesn't contain the lines mentioned in the thread.

Comment: can you use jquery or js?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to remove breadcrumbs. Please delete from you view this code with all inside it:

```
<div id="crumbs">
</div>
```

Or you can also edit your CSS file:

```
div#crumbs {
display: none;
}
```